# How to change specific values 1 by 1 of a worksheet based on conditions from another worksheet in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the value of the columns of breakdown voltage in "Breakdown" worksheet whenever it is 1E+17 into the correct value based on the data from another worksheet called "data".

The condition is whenever the before current / after current or after current/ before current >= 1000 in every column of current in "Data" worksheet, I will record its corresponding voltage and replace the incorrect data in "Breakdown" worksheet.

My program gives me 0 for the highlighted point in "Breakdown" worksheet instead.

Picture 1 ("data" worksheet)
[image]

Before("Breakdown" worksheet)
[image]

I want("Breakdown" worksheet)
[image]

My code:

```
Sub test()

Dim correctvbd As Long
Dim a As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheets("Breakdown").Range("C" & Sheets("Breakdown").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

i = 2

starting = 3
j = starting ' STARTING POINT FOR READING voltage

Do While Sheets("data").Cells(j, i) <> ""         
                
    If Sheets("data").Cells(j, i) / Sheets("data").Cells(j - 1, i) >= 1000 Or _
      Sheets("data").Cells(j - 1, i) / Sheets("data").Cells(j, i) >= 1000 Then
        correctvbd = Sheets("data").Cells(j - 1, i - 1) 'record the point where correct Breakdown voltage is found
        Exit Do
                                                     
    Else
        j = j + 1 'continue to search for Breakdown voltage down the row for that column if it is not found yet
 
    End If
                             
    For a = 1 To lastrow                                                     
        If Sheets("Breakdown").Cells(a, 3).Value = 1E+17 Then
            Sheets("Breakdown").Cells(a, 3).Value = correctvbd
        End If      
    Next
Loop

' the upper five lens for sensor
i = i + 2 ' NEXT data point for next set of data data
j = starting 'Starting point for next set of voltage data

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem could be, that you are defining correctvdb long:

```
Dim correctvbd As Long
```

It could be double.
Also I think the line is missing the .value at the end

```
correctvbd = Sheets("data").Cells(j - 1, i - 1)
```

Comment: Sorry, more problems. In case you have to correct something: `correctvbd = Sheets("data").Cells(j - 1, i - 1).Value`. Your `exit do` jumping over the line `Sheets("Breakdown").Cells(a, 3).Value = correctvbd` to the loop, so no value will be written.